# MySQL tables diagram and cascade

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I want to migrate to MySQL from SQL Server. Nevertheless i got some question. In SQL Server there was possibility to create diagram and choose tables which should be shown there. Then using connectors i was anle to connect one table to another by targeting PK field to FK field in another table, morover i could set cascade for update and delete. Is such functionality available also in MySQL?

Comment: this is not a sql server or mysql functionality but a functionality of the workbecnh you use to interact with the database

Comment: you mean is it possible similar way to do in myqsl workbench?

Comment: There are plenty of workbench tools for MySQL. Some will probably include that functionality